# Как вывести динамический массив в window form textbox

Tags: массивы, c++-cli

Есть функция `task1()` которая возвращает массив, и передает кнопке, которая в свою очередь передает его `textBox`.

[Кнопка](http://take.ms/EgUMz)

```
#pragma once
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
namespace Lab
{
        using namespace std;

        void initArr(int* arrPtr, const int size)
        {
                for (int* arrPtrCpy = arrPtr; arrPtrCpy < arrPtr + size; ++arrPtrCpy)
                {
                        *arrPtrCpy = rand() % 51 - 25;
                }
        }

        /*int printArr(int* arrPtr, const int size)
        {
                for (int* arrPtrCpy = arrPtr; arrPtrCpy < arrPtr + size; ++arrPtrCpy)
                {
                        if (arrPtr + size == arrPtrCpy)
                        {
                                return *arrPtrCpy;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                printArr(arrPtr, size);
                        }
                }

        }*/

        bool isElementExists(const int* arrPtr, const int size, const int item)
        {
                bool isExists = false;

                for (const int* arrPtrCpy = arrPtr; arrPtrCpy < arrPtr + size; ++arrPtrCpy)
                {
                        if (*arrPtrCpy == item)
                        {
                                isExists = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                return isExists;
        }

        bool isElementExists(const int* arrPtr, const int* endArrPtr, const int item)
        {
                bool isExists = false;

                for (const int* arrPtrCpy = arrPtr; arrPtrCpy < endArrPtr; ++arrPtrCpy)
                {
                        if (*arrPtrCpy == item)
                        {
                                isExists = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                return isExists;
        }

        int conver(int arrPtr, const int size, int &mass)
        {

                for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                        *mass[i] = *arrPtr[i]-48;
                }

        }


        int task1()
        {
                int sizeA = 5;
                int sizeB = 5;

                int* arrAPtr = new int[sizeA];
                initArr(arrAPtr, sizeA);
                int* arrBPtr = new int[sizeB];
                initArr(arrBPtr, sizeB);

                //printArr(arrAPtr, sizeA);
                //printArr(arrBPtr, sizeB);

                int sizeC = 0;
                for (int* arrAPtrCpy = arrAPtr; arrAPtrCpy < arrAPtr + sizeA; ++arrAPtrCpy)
                {
                        if (!isElementExists(arrAPtr, arrAPtrCpy, *arrAPtrCpy) && !isElementExists(arrBPtr, sizeB, *arrAPtrCpy))
                        {
                                ++sizeC;
                        }
                }
                int* arrCPtr = new int[sizeC];
                for (int* arrAPtrCpy = arrAPtr, *arrCPtrCpy = arrCPtr; arrAPtrCpy < arrAPtr + sizeA; ++arrAPtrCpy)
                {
                        if (!isElementExists(arrAPtr, arrAPtrCpy, *arrAPtrCpy) && !isElementExists(arrBPtr, sizeB, *arrAPtrCpy))
                        {
                                *arrCPtrCpy = *arrAPtrCpy;
                                ++arrCPtrCpy;
                        }
                }

                char *mass= new char [sizeC];
                delete[] arrAPtr;
                delete[] arrBPtr;

                return arrCPtr;


                delete[] arrCPtr;

        }



}
```

В данный момент у меня выводится первый элемент массива.

**Вопрос:** как мне вывести весь массив?

Так как на курсах нам еще не говорили что такое ООП и классы. Мне надо просто шаблон.

Хочу преподу домашку отправлять в нормальном виде, а не по 10 разных сорс файлов.

Comment: Не хотим смотреть скрины, с них код некопипастится.

Comment: и причём тут знание ООП?

Comment: [code](http://pasteall.org/78052/cpp)

Comment: Если бы я знал, то не спрашивал :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По порядку

Во-первых:

```
return arrCPtr;
delete[] arrCPtr;
```

В данном случае `delete` не сработает, так как после `return`, происходит выход из функции.

Во-вторых:

Тип возврата из функции у вас `int`, однако на деле вы возвращаете указатель `return arrCPtr;`, который имеет тип `int*`

В-третьих:

Чтобы вывести в `textBox` все значения переменных, вам нужно не просто сконвертировать в строку возвращённое значение, а предварительно склеить их в одну строку, например таким образом:

```
int* array = Lab::task1();
String^ str = gcnew String("");
for(int i = 0; i<arraySize; ++i){
   textBoxString += System::Convert::ToString(array[i])+" ";
}

textBox1->Text = textBoxString;
```

`arraySize` - длина массива.

Comment: Да, про освобождение памяти я знаю, хотел у препада уточнить как его освободить. А как  мне вмести с массивом еще и его размер передать или можно воспользоватся sizeof? И еще у меня компилятор ругается [картинка](http://take.ms/hXQAr)

Comment: sizeof не подойдёт, т.к. у вас указатель, а не сам массив, в этом случае sizeof вернёт размер только размер самого указателя (обычно 4 байта)

Comment: по поводу размера, можете передать в функцию `task1` указатель и выставить его в функции, делается примерно так `void func(int* size){*size = 5; }` и вызвать его в программе так `int* size = new int; func(size); //size = 5` после выхода из функции, указатель будет иметь значение установленное в функции

Comment: @ВладКиндюшов String поправил

Comment: Благодарю все заоаботало, в итоге получился такой код:
` private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
 {
  int *size = new int;
  int* arra = Lab::task1(size);
  String^ str = gcnew String("");
  for (int i = 0; i < *size; ++i) 
  {
   str += Convert::ToString(Convert::ToInt32(arra[i]))+(Convert::ToString(" "));
  }
  textBox1->Text = str;
  
  `